# Route traffic to a docker container based on subdomain

Tags: docker, wildcard-subdomain

I have wildcard dns pointed to my server e.g. *.domain.com

I'd like to route each subdomain to it's own docker container.
So that box1.domain.com goes to the appropriate docker container.
This should work for any traffic primarily HTTP and SSH.

Or perhaps the port can be part of the subdomain e.g. 80.box1.domain.com.
I will have lots of docker containers so the solution should be dynamic not hard-coded for every container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went with [interlock](https://github.com/ehazlett/interlock) to route http traffic using the [nginx plugin](https://github.com/ehazlett/interlock/tree/master/plugins/nginx).
I settled on using a random port for each SSH connection as I couldn't get it work using the subdomain alone.

Answer (score 16):

Another solution would be to use https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.

This tool automatically forwards requests to the appropriate container (based on subdomain via the ***VIRTUAL_HOST*** container environment variable).

For instance, if you want to redirect *box1.domain.com* to a container, simply set the ***VIRTUAL_HOST*** container environment variable to "***box1.domain.com***".

Here is a detailed tutorial I wrote about it: http://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker.

Comment: Good to know, that works in a similar way to interlock. Does it facilitate SSH?

Comment: Yes it seems to. I don't know in which way it could facilitate SSH as Nginx-proxy does handle HTTP requests.

Comment: If you want to SSH into your Docker containers using subdomains, I think you can add a CNAME DNS rule pointing to your host IP. Exposing SSH container's port to host (hence to public), let's say 1020, would allow you to SSH into your container using your subdomain: ssh -p 1020 sub.domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use the Apache mod_rewrite RewriteMap method. It's very performant when used against a text file, but it can call a script if desired. There is [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641989) that covers the script variant pretty well.

If you want to avoid Apache, the good folks over at dotCloud created Hipache to do the routing for their PaaS services. They even [documented the different things](http://blog.dotcloud.com/under-the-hood-dotcloud-http-routing-layer) they tried before building their own solution. I found a reference to tsuru.io using hipache exactly for routing to docker containers, so that definitely validates it for this purpose.

Comment: Here is a link to the tsuru.io mention I referenced: [tsuru.io](http://docs.tsuru.io/en/0.4.0/provisioners/docker/architecture.html).

Comment: Also, here is some information on doing dynamic reverse proxying with nginx and dnsmasq, though I find it a bit awkward: [nginx + dnsmasq](http://www.cmdln.org/2009/07/12/transparent_dynamic-reverse-proxy-with-nginx/)

Comment: Also take a look at the following StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497564/assigning-vhosts-to-docker-ports?rq=1

Comment: Do any of these solutions support SSH traffic to the containers?

Answer (score 1):

my answer may come to late but when you use docker you don't really need ssh to connect to your containers. with the `docker exec` command, you can run shell command directly in your running container.

here is my advice use the [nginx proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) container listed at the beginning for configuring sub-domains. and run [portainer](http://portainer.io/overview.html#demo) on your host in order to have a visual overview of your Containers, images, logs and even execute command in it all of this through the portainer gui.

Answer (score 0):

I used apache proxypresevehost

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:4533/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:4533/"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).